# Extend jQuery constructor/init

Tags: jquery, overriding

Is there any chance to extend `jQuery`s constructor to pass in a custom type?

```
var $someObject = $(someCustomObject);
```

As seen from `jQuery` source is calling internally the `init`-function which I want to extend to add a check like

```
// ... some code before (default handling)
else if ( typeof selector === "myCustomType" ){
    // do things with my object to initialize the jQuery
}
```

I don't want to change the source of `jQuery` as I still need to be able to upgrade to a newer version.

Coming from a `C#` point I'm thinking of some kind of `virtual` method handling where I can extend the `init` like:

```
jQuery.fn.init = function(selector, context){
    // check for my custom type
    if(typeof selector === "myCustomType"){
        // do my stuff here
    }else{
        // call the default init which will not break when updating jQuery
        jQuery.old.init(selector, context);
    }
}
```